# Using d3 with URL query strings

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to be able to provide URLs to access different views of visualizations that I've created. For example, some of the visualizations change for each year or for each variable. When the user changes the year or the variable depicted, I'd like to update the URL. For example, from

```
index.html?year=1790&variable=population
```

to

```
index.html?year=1820&variable=populationdensity
```

Then, when a visitor comes to one of those URLs, to initialize the visualization using the query string.

Perhaps I'll have to write this myself, but has anyone done something similar or have sample code for how to do this?

Comment: what technology are you uysing? is this going to be a SPA or a server side page, do you have JS router in place? if you are goign to just rely on JS you can always parse the query string and apply what ever parameters you have to the d3 script.

Comment: I intent to do this entirely in client-side JavaScript.

Comment: ok what JS frameworks are you using?

Comment: Just d3. I just want the users to be able to bookmark/link to more than the initial state of the visualization.

Comment: There's nothing for this in D3.

Answer (score 2):

on your script you can do something like

```
var i=0;
var telem;
var search_values=location.search.replace('\?','').split('&');
var query={}
for(i=0;i<search_values.length;i++){
    telem=search_values[i].split('=');
    query[telem[0]]=telem[1];
}

console.log(query);
```

after this the query variable should hold all the key:values of your query string. this of should be contained inside a function to avoid polluting the global scope

Comment: I assume that `var tele` should be `var telem`