# Getting query string at end of URL and using it to fetch data

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

I am using window.search.location to get the query string of my current URL. This query string is then appended to a php url in my JS file, and uses JSON to get the data from a PHP script.

No data is returned if I try to do this. However, if I hardcode the url path, it does work. Is there any small reason why appending the query string would cause my URL path to be invalid?

The current URL for this example is: localhost/Sandbox/examplefile.html?Region=Testing

Example file contains references to an external JS file whose code is below.

JS Code (not working):

```
var queryString = window.location.search;

var url = "./php/process.php" + queryString;

//Get list of current users
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {

    console.log(data[1]);

});
```

JS Example Hard-coded (working):

```
var url = "./php/process.php?Region=Testing"

//Get list of current users
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {

    console.log(data[1]);

});
```

I can use console.log and document.write to prove to myself that the queryString value is "?Region=Testing"

Any advice?

EDIT:

The code seems to work occasionally. When it doesn't work, it returns an undefined array. Does this have to do with JSON working asynchronously perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_GET` to do that job in PHP. Your code would be something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['region']) && strlen($_GET['region'])>0) {
    /***
    * The value of $_GET['region'] is Testing if the URL is ./php/process.php?Region=Testing
    * And so you can use that variable to do your stuff
    ***/
    DoSomething($_GET['region']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer saved my day.

[Using d3 with URL query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000146/using-d3-with-url-query-strings)

```
var i=0;
var tele;
var search_values=location.search.replace('\?','').split('&');
var query={}
for(i=0;i<search_values.length;i++){
   telem=search_values[i].split('=');
   query[telem[0]]=telem[1];
    }

 console.log(query);
```

Once you get your query string, you access its key using `Object.keys()`, like so:

```
var your_params = Object.keys(query).map(function(key){return query[key];});
```

Now you can pass it in `d3.json` like so:

```
d3.json("./php/process.php?<name of your query>" + [your_params], function(error, data) {

   });
```